# Replace power supply on late 2005 G5

Tags: mac, hardware, hardware-recommendation, g5, power-mac

I recently bought an old G5 to use as a server.  Whilst there the guy had another G5 that I bought for spares.

The 'spares' G5 is a newer model with better GPU / CPU etc so I intend on swapping them over.  The main issue I have is that the power connector on the newer G5 is the rectangular design and I don't have a plug for it.

My decision was to remove the PSU's from both machines and swap them over.  I've dont this plenty of times with normal pc's in the past and haven't encountered any problems but I recently read that the power supplies in G5's are very specific.

Before I can any further I'd like some advice on the above.  hopefully someone might've attempted similar.

The model numbers are: CK337084NVA & CK60903YUV0

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else:  Don't tear apart the G5 without knowing with absolute certainty the PSU will fit.  These two were different.  Mission is a fail.